# Lambda Expression: Add to nested HashSet inline

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can this be rewritten in a single statement without if-is-null validation?

```
 var group = ParentHashList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GroupId == someGroupId);
            if (group != null) group.ChildHashList.Add(newItem);
```

Comment: Why do you need it to rewrite? It has two different operations - searching for group and adding item to that group. As for me they should be separated

Comment: Less code is better than more code

Comment: I did not say always,  But in this case, it would be.  In SQL for example, this would be done in a single select statement.  LINQ is modeled after SQL

Comment: @LastTribunal: If you wanted to do it in one statement you would need to be able to call `Add` with `null`. Also you can write this in a nearly identical format as SQL but it will hide the intent as working with single items is possible in C# and more straightforward than lists (especially lists of length 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient. But if you do want a one-liner, you may consider this one:

```
ParentHashList
    .Where(a => a.GroupId == someGroupId)
    .Take(1)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(a => a.ChildHashList.Add(newItem);
```

A straightforward `foreach` looks better:

```
foreach(var a in ParentHashList
                 .Where(a => a.GroupId == someGroupId)
                 .Take(1))
    a.ChildHashList.Add(newItem);
```

Comment: Its not the same. OP has filter by ID, and you are taking just first item

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Thanks, I overlooked it. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done, **but should not**. Because: (a) not explicit, (b) far uglier (c) dirty.

```
var group = ParentHashList
    .Where(x => x.GroupId == someGroupId)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => { x.ChildHashList.Add(newItem); return true; });
```